# Find missing pairs (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Lets say that I have a table called `customer_accounts` that looks like this:

Table: CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS

```
+------------------+--------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID (PK) |  ACCOUNT_ID  | 
+------------------+--------------+
|        1         |          5   |
|        1         |          6   | 
|        1         |          8   | 
+------------------+--------------+
```

And I have another table called `distinct_account_pairs` that looks like this:

Table: DISTINCT_ACCOUNT_PAIRS (before)

```
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID (PK) |  ACCOUNT_ID1  | ACCOUNT_ID2   |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
|        1         |          6    |       5       |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

How do I populate the distinct_account_pairs table with the missing pairs for each CUSTOMER_ID? In this example 5 and 8, 6 and 8 are missing for PK CUSTOMER_ID 1 in distinct_account_pairs, so after it should look something like this. Note that distinct_account_pairs could have account_id1 < account_id2 or vice versa. The pairs just need to be distinct for each CUSTOMER_ID.

Table: DISTINCT_ACCOUNT_PAIRS (after)

```
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID (PK) |  ACCOUNT_ID1  | ACCOUNT_ID2   |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
|        1         |          6    |       5       |
|        1         |          5    |       8       |
|        1         |          6    |       8       |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I assume PK means "primary key"? You do realize, don't you, that the column you marked (PK) in `CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS` is not, in fact, "primary key" in that table? It can't be - it has duplicate values in it.

Comment: Regarding your question: so, the pairs that already exist in the second table must remain as they are (even if `ACCOUNT_ID1 > ACCOUNT_ID2`, but the **missing** pairs can all be added with `ACCOUNT_ID1 < ACCOUNT_ID2` in all cases? Also, you need to change the second table (perhaps through an `INSERT` statement), rather than just write a `SELECT` query for the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You would generate all the pairs and then compare them:

```
select ca1.customer_id, ca1.account_id, ca2.account_id
from customer_accounts ca1 join
     customer_accounts ca2
     on ca1.customer_id = ca2.customer_id and
        ca1.account_id < ca2.account_id left join
     distinct_account_pairs dap
     on dap.customer_id = ca1.customer_id and
        dap.account_id1 in (ca1.account_id, ca2.account_id) and
        dap.account_id2 in (ca1.account_id, ca2.account_id) 
where dap.customer_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with self join and not exists:

```
 create table CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS ( CUSTOMER_ID int,  ACCOUNT_ID  int);

 insert into CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS values(        1         ,          5   );
 insert into CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS values(        1         ,          6   ); 
 insert into CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS values(        1         ,          8   );

 create table DISTINCT_ACCOUNT_PAIRS ( CUSTOMER_ID int,  ACCOUNT_ID1  int, ACCOUNT_ID2   int);
 insert into DISTINCT_ACCOUNT_PAIRS values(        1         ,          6    ,       5       );
```

Insert Query:

```
 insert into DISTINCT_ACCOUNT_PAIRS 
 select a.CUSTOMER_ID,a.ACCOUNT_ID,b.ACCOUNT_ID from CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS a inner join CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS b
 on a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CUSTOMER_ID and a.ACCOUNT_ID < b.ACCOUNT_ID
 and not exists 
               (select 1 from DISTINCT_ACCOUNT_PAIRS d where d.CUSTOMER_ID=a.CUSTOMER_ID
               and ((d.ACCOUNT_ID1=a.ACCOUNT_ID and d.ACCOUNT_ID2=b.ACCOUNT_ID)
               or (d.ACCOUNT_ID1=b.ACCOUNT_ID and d.ACCOUNT_ID2=a.ACCOUNT_ID))
               );
```

Query: to select from DISTINCT_ACCOUNT_PAIRS

```
 SELECT * FROM DISTINCT_ACCOUNT_PAIRS;
```

Output:

| CUSTOMER_ID | ACCOUNT_ID1 | ACCOUNT_ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 | 8 |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8475d855829303a435ab7a47089a4f52)*